How to use constraints to simulate hinges?
You can use rigidbodies and that kind of works, but only in animation. My goal is to drag a part that is connected via what should be hinges and the rest to act accordingly. Also, with animation, there is no ability to drag something, only to apply forces to the whole structure, not to a specific element for the rest to act accordingly.
I am asking here, because AI cannot answer that.

i don't really understand what the problem is? yes, you found out right, you can move objects if the animation is running and they behave physically "right" in the limits of Blender. So just add a hinge constraint and this will work too. Or did you never add a hinge constraint and you don't know how to use that?

you can "apply forces" e.g. via checking "animated" in rigid body settings and just keyframe that. By that you have total control over what you wanna do. But tbh you should give us a detailed example what you are trying to achieve than talking about "in general". Else i can only give you the advice to watch some rigid body beginner tutorials.

Of course this works only in animation. Blender is no game engine. Things only start to "react" physically simulated if there is time passing, i.e. the animation running. Not when you are in static editing mode.

Hello, have you checked connected rigid bodies and in what way is it not good for you?

Hello, Zurechtweiser.. I think you really have to clarify: that you are using a Hinge Conmstraint, and that the host is being animated/forced in a way that leads you to expect a result.

Consider copy-location & copy-rotation constraints.  And hmmm what is KI?

@james_t german for artificial intelligence

@GordonBrinkmann understood the assignment. Do others agree with him? BTW, doesn't blender also have a game engine part?

@Zurechtweiser Blender once had a game engine part but this gone for years now. Today there is UPBGE, a game engine forked from the old Blender game engine, but it is no part of "regular" Blender.

@GordonBrinkmann Where would you simulate hinges with real time interaction?

@Zurechtweiser Never needed to do this. And if so it would most likely not be Blender so I could not help you on this site with it anyway.
